# File System Task from SSIS not working in SQL Server Agent (no errors)

Tags: windows, ssis, directory, etl, sql-server-agent

I have a File system Task that does some ETL (moves some .txt files, copies to other directory, renames) between servers.

[image]

When I execute this package from Visual Studio, it works well, it copies the files from one server to the other, renames, and archives. 
but when I set it with a job to run from the SQL Server Agent, it finishes without error, but it doesn't operate with any file, (no copy, no rename, no move) not even at the same server level.

- I have given full permission to the SQL server agent service name for
  the folders in which the files are located and have to be put.
- The package runs in X64 and 32 bit mode without error.
- Package security is set to "DontSaveSensitive"
- Run64BitRuntime is set to "true"

this is the history log from running the job:

> Executed as user: USERNAME. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package
>   Utility  Version 12.0.2548.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  3:08:56 PM  DTExec: The
>   package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).  Started:  3:08:56 PM 
>   Finished: 3:08:57 PM  Elapsed:  0.688 seconds.  The package executed
>   successfully.  The step succeeded.

The paths that I use for the package are all in the format:

```
\\ServerName\directory\subDir
```

My question would be, how can I know why the File System Task is not actually working?

I don't know how to check on logs more detailed to what I see on the SQL Server Agent to know what is actually happening, and if it's a permission issue I believe that I should see errors. I'm not sure about what is happening at this point.
Please let me know if there is more info I should add to help.

EDIT: I'm adding logging files from what I execute from VisualStudio (the one that works) and when the package is called from SQL Server Agent.

I will replace server names and usernames but I'll show what permits they have on different folders.

```
**MyUsername**  = Username when I run from visual studio
**ORIGIN**  =  Origin server from where I copy the files
**DESTINATION** =  Destination server where I put them and manipulate
**SqlServerAgent**  = ServerAgent name
```

Log files from my computer when I run from visual studio (and the package operates with the files):

[Log in Pastebin (VisualStudio)](https://pastebin.com/jrZMmJZr)

and the log files for when I run from the SQL Server Agent:

[log sql server agent](https://pastebin.com/cQWUidu8)

And information about the permits:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to look at the logs in the the SSISDB. My money is on it'll say that the For Each Loop container found no files.

Comment: From the log you mentioned above, you are using a proxy account to run this agent jon (`Executed as user:`), make sute that this user has the read/write permissions over all files and folders needed

Comment: @Larnu I'm running the job as FileSystem from the SQL server agent, how can I check logs there?

Comment: @Hadi I gave permission to that user, although when setting the job it says that it will execute as "SQL Server Agent" so I looked for the logon of the SQL Server Agent user and gave permissions to that user.

Comment: @Larnu  I though that might be (hence no errors) but the files are there, and when I execute from Visual Studio it does move them around, so the For Each Loop is picking them up

Comment: Why are you using the File System deployment system still? SSISDB is vastly better

Comment: @Larnu I'm running with SQL server 2014, I don't know about it, but mostly, because when I first read about SSIS recommendations were to run with File System, so I did that

Comment: Those must have been some very outdated recommendations, @Baldie47 . Filesystem is probably the worst of the three deployment methods in my view. Unfortunately, is agent *really* isn't given you a reason, then there's little you can do to find out but I suspect the account really has access. If you do switch to SSISDB, then the logs will be infinitely more informative.

Comment: @Larnu I will work on doing the switch then :) I hope is not a big hassle, I'll start investigating on it. thank you!

Comment: @Larnu  I just tried to do the setup for SSISDB, I found out why I can't. when I try to create a folder for for the Catalog, it gives me an error since I'musing an account with SQL server authentication, it tells me to use one with Windows Authentication, but due to company policies, there is no W.A. account with folder creation privileges

Comment: You don't have any windows authentication accounts? That sounds really odd. Trusted connections are a fundamental in any AD environment. The policies of the company appear to be the problem here. I can only suggest you look over the permissions of the Agent and Service account, as they clearly aren't high enough to access the directories.

Comment: To surface your problem, add `/rep EIW`. As Larnu speculates, you'll see a warning/Information message specifying the account found no files which likely means it's permissions. The corporate policy against Windows Account is likely going to be problematic as "someone" needs to be able to access the network drive \\server\directory\subdir and local users isn't going to be that

Comment: @Larnu I have added more information

Comment: Looks like i was right: *"The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty."*

Comment: yes, I agree on that, but the directory is not empty, so the user is not "seeing" the files. this should be a setting on the viewing permits for the sqlServerAgent user, right? but I have set all permits for that user...

Comment: It's either the permission (which I am very confident of), possibly due to double hopping, *or* you have a filter in your For each Container which is resulting in no rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, wasn't in the Parameters, or permit.
The issue was that the For Each Loop was pointing to a mapped drive instead of full qualified path like the rest of the folders, hence the For Each Loop wasn't finding anything. 
However the permits were ok, just wasn't finding anything.